# SQL: How to use "ORDER BY" and "GROUP BY" together?

Tags: sql

I have a database with a list of passengers and the weights of their luggage. I need to display each unique passenger and the total weight of their luggage (passengers can have more than 1 entry for luggage) and display it in descending order.

My current solution that doesnt work is as follows:

```
SELECT PassengerID, Weight
FROM Baggage
GROUP BY PassengerID
ORDER BY Weight DESC;
```

Comment: Keep in mind that a group by clause without an aggregate function in the select clause is deprecated and will eventually be done away with.

Comment: @TGray, deprecated? According to who? Since when?

Comment: @jarlh In versions 5.6 and newer, strict sql mode must be turned off in order for things like non-aggregate group by and zero dates to be permitted.

Comment: @TGray, are you talking about MySQL here? I was talking about the ANSI SQL standard. (The only tag is SQL, which means ISO/ANSI SQL is assumed.) BTW, isn't that MySQL new restriction the opposite, you must list non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY, just like ANSI SQL always has been?

Comment: Given the structure of his query, I assumed he was using MySQL because a group by without an aggregate function in the select clause or without a having clause will not compile otherwise.  The problem is less having to list non-aggregated columns in the GROUP BY, and more that there is a GROUP BY without any aggregation.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you just want to SUM the weights:

```
SELECT PassengerID, SUM(Weight) AS TotalWeight
FROM Baggage
GROUP BY PassengerID
ORDER BY SUM(Weight) DESC;
```

Comment: I'd do `ORDER BY TotalWeight DESC` instead.

Comment: @jarlh - You can't order by a column alias in standard sql, and must instead use the expression again.  I have no idea if any particular DBs (I'm looking at you, MySQL) break the standard here and allow it.

Comment: @Donnie, of course ANSI SQL lets you order by column aliases.

Comment: You can also use column indexes.  here, "Order by 2 desc" would do the same thing.

Comment: @jarlh - You are, of course, correct.  I was thinking about group by.

Comment: @Donnie, order by ordinal position was removed from the ANSI SQL standard in 1992.

Comment: @Donnie, yes, GROUP BY may only list columns, not column aliases (or other expressions.)

Comment: @jarlh - Wait, seriously?  I've never ran into any DB that didn't support it.  Interesting.  yay, standards. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT passenger_Name, SUM(weight) AS 'Total Weight'
FROM baggage
GROUP BY passenger_name
ORDER BY 'Total Weight' DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need an aggregate function to go with your GROUP BY - in this case it would be SUM:-

```
SELECT 
  PassengerID, 
  SUM(Weight)
FROM Baggage
GROUP BY PassengerID
ORDER BY SUM(Weight) DESC;
```

Comment: Invalid ORDER BY, Weight cannot be used there.

Comment: Noted - not sure why I missed that